# Confirmar antes de submeter função javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

Quando submeto um formulário, através de `onsubmit(checkFormIsCorrect())`, chamo esta função javascript que vai validar várias situações e submeter ou não o form.

Nesta função:

```
function checkFormIsCorrect() {
    if (!$('div.has-error').length > 0) {
        return displayAlertify('confirm',
                'Confirme todos os dados antes de submeter');
    }
    return false;
}
```

A função `displayAlertify(...)` mostra uma caixa com os botões "OK" e "CANCEL", retornando `true` ou `false`.

O problema é que não consigo parar a execução do código até receber o return da função `displayAlertify(...)`.

Comment: não faltou o `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: posta o seu código html.

Comment: Não deu pra entender seu problema direito. Qual é seu objetivo?

Comment: <form onsubmit="return checkFormIsCorrect();" class="form_1"
   method="post">
....
.....
   <div class="form_line">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn2 btn-primary btn-block"
     name="submit_new_user">Registar</button>
   </div>
  </form>

Comment: O objetivo é conseguir confirmar ou cancelar a submissão do formulário, clicando nos botões da caixa 'OK' ou 'CANCEL'

Comment: Você deveria mostrar como você declara `displayAlertify`

Comment: function displayAlertify(message) {
 alertify.confirm(message, function(e) {
  if (e) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 });
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `displayAlertify` retorna nada.

*código expandido dos comentários*

```
function displayAlertify(message) {

    /* escopo anterior */

    alertify.confirm(message, function(e) {

        /* novo escopo */

        if (e) {
            /* retorna para onde foi chamado */
            return true;
        } else
            /* retorna para onde foi chamado */
            return false;
    });
}
```

– O callback em `alertify.confirm` não executa o `return` no escopo anterior. Aliás, não faria sentido.

Além disso, uma vez que o callback de `onsubmit` executa, não é possível retornar um valor para sí ainda, pois a execução *expira*. É assim com todas funções. Então, quando o usuário provavelmente confirmar a alerta, o callback de `onsubmit` já vai ter expirado antes.

E isso é suficiente, quebrar o envio do formulário até que a alerta de `alertify` seja confirmada, então enviar novamente.

```
function checkFormIsCorrect() {
    if ($('div.has-error').length <= 0) {
        displayAlertify('confirm', 'Confirme todos os dados antes de submeter');
    }
    /* break */
    return false;
}

function displayAlertify(message) {
    alertify.confirm(message, function(e) {
        /* submete o formulário */
        if (e) $('form')[0].submit();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido.

Ficou assim:

```
function checkFormIsCorrect() {
    if (!$('div.has-error').length > 0) {
         displayAlertify('confirm',
                 'Confirme todos os dados antes de submeter');
    }
    return false;
}

function displayAlertify(type, message) {
    alertify.confirm(message, function(e) {
        if (e) $('form')[0].submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 }
```

Comment: Coloquei o return false fora do ir porque se o bloco if não for executado, a função tem de retornar false.

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido que você declarou o `!`, agora entendi... x_X porque você retornou `false`. Mudei o operador `>` para `<=` e tirei o `!` na minha resposta, assim talvez fique menos confuso

Comment: Estou a conseguir submeter e cancelar a submissão quando quero.
Ele submete o formulário quando entra em ambos os if de cada função.

Resumindo:
a execução começa entrando na função checkFormIsCorrect(), entra no if(...), entra na função displayAlertify(...) e faz submit do formulário:
Se não entrar no primeiro if, retorna false.